# Nested list to a dictionary of index counts

Tags: python, list, numpy, dictionary, keras

I'm very new to Python 3 and I'm working with Keras sigmoid activations which produce a nested list of probabilities.

I have a nested list that looks something like this:

```
[[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5]
 [0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1]
 ...
 [0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.2]]
```

What I want to do is convert this list into a dictionary of indices wherein each index key has a corresponding frequency count of how many times in the list it meets a certain condition.

For example, given the three rows in the sample nested list above and given the condition:

```
element > 0.2
```

It will build the following dictionary:

```
[
    0: 0
    1: 1
    2: 3
    3: 2
    4: 1
    5: 1
]
```

This is because across the three nested lists, the value at index 0 is never greater than 0.2, the value at index 1 is greater than 0.2 only once (at the second nested list), the value at index 2 is greater than 0.2 for all the nested lists, the value at index 3 is greater than 0.2 for two nested lists (namely the second and third nested list), and so on.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `a` as the list of lists of same lengths, we could convert to an array, giving us a `2D` array. Then, compare against `2`  and then sum the `True` matches  along each column, as the counts. Finally setup the output dictionary from it.

Thus, one implementation would be -

```
C = (np.asarray(a)>0.2).sum(axis=0)
dict_out = {i:c for i,c in enumerate(C)}
```

`np.count_nonzero` could also be used in place `np.sum` for summing matches there.

Sample run -

```
In [209]: a
Out[209]: 
[[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5],
 [0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1],
 [0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.2]]

In [210]: C = (np.asarray(a)>0.2).sum(axis=0)

In [211]: C
Out[211]: array([0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1])

In [212]: {i:c for i,c in enumerate(C)}
Out[212]: {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 1}
```

---

**Handling ragged sublists**

For ragged sublists (lists having different lengths in input list), we could convert it to a regular array upon filling values with a invalid specifier (NaN seems suitable here) and then sum along the appropriate axis. Thus, to handle such a case, the modified implementation would be -

```
from itertools import izip_longest # For Python3, use zip_longest

C = (np.array(list(izip_longest(*a, fillvalue=np.nan)))>0.2).sum(1)
dict_out = {i:c for i,c in enumerate(C)}
```

Sample run -

```
In [253]: a
Out[253]: 
[[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7, 0.2],
 [0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1],
 [0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1]]

In [254]: C = (np.array(list(izip_longest(*a, fillvalue=np.nan)))>0.2).sum(1)

In [255]: {i:c for i,c in enumerate(C)}
Out[255]: {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just write a simple code

```
a = [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5], [0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1],
     [0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.2]]
dic = {'0': 0, '1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 0}
var = [x*0 for x in range(5)]

for array in a:
    for i in range(5):
        if array[i] > 0.2:
            var[i] += 1

dic = {'0': var[0], '1': var[1], '2': var[2], '3': var[3], '4': var[4]}
print(dic)
```

Answer (score 1):

While Divakar gives a really good answer with `numpy`, here's another way that doesn't use `numpy` which uses `zip`, `list unpacking`, `enumerate`, `sum` and `dictionary comprehension`. Just replace the `i > 0.2` with what ever condition you want it to be:

```
x = [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5], [0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1], [0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.2]]

print({current_index:sum(i > 0.2 for i in values) for current_index, values in enumerate(zip(*x))})

>> {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 1}
```